# How to initialize a list<type> with consecutive values?

Tags: c#, .net, list, initialization

I have class like this

```
public class Sample
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

var sampleValues = new List<Sample>(){
        new Sample(){ A = "a1", B = 1 },
        new Sample(){ A = "a2", B = 2 },
        new Sample(){ A = "a3", B = 3 },
        new Sample(){ A = "a4", B = 4 },
        .....
        new Sample(){ A ="a30", B = 30}
    };
```

Is there any easy way of initializing it with 30 consecutive values as shown?

Comment: I've formatted your sample code (and changed a bit) to align with default C# coding guidelines (upper case for Classes and Properties). Feel free to revert if it does not align with your style/goals.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).ASPX) like:

```
List<Sample> samvalues = Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
                               .Select(r => new Sample {A = "a" + r, B = r})
                               .ToList();
```

Or

```
List<Sample> samvalues = Enumerable.Range(1, 30)
                    .Select(r => new Sample {A = String.Format("{0}{1}", "a", r), B = r})
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: @mahindar, you are welcome. I believe your code in question is not a real code, But if you are using similar naming conventions then see [General Naming Conventions - Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx) for your class names, properties etc.

Comment: Actually it was just a sample code to make it easy to understand.

Comment: +1. I've updated sample code in question. Consider updating your one. Also may note that `new Sample() {....}` does not need `()`: new Sample { A = ... }`.